# Creating a Bootstrap carousel from existing markup which uses a full width background image

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a website written in Bootstrap 3.3.6. One of the pages has a "banner" which has been created by making a `background-image` in a `.container-fluid`:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="background-image: url('/banner-placeholder.jpg'); height: 555px; background-repeat: no-repeat;  background-position: center;">
```

Within the `.container-fluid` there are other Bootstrap div's which contain a form and some areas of text. I've included a shortened version of the markup to indicate the structure:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <h3>Heading 1</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>Heading 2</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <!-- Form -->

            <div class="row">
                <h3>Heading 4</h3>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Instead of having just a static background image (`background-image: url('/banner-placeholder.jpg');`) I want to have a carousel of sliding images. When the carousel image changes, the "content" on top of the image (inside `.container`) also needs changing.

I don't understand how it's possible to use the Bootstrap carousel in a way like this. Firstly, how can I get the same effect as `background-image:` if I'm having to use an `<img src="">` tag? Secondly, I understand the Carousel will toggle between `.item`. So, do I have to include the markup for my "content" inside `.item` in the same place as the `<img src="">` tag?

I understand the basics of how the carousel works. But I don't understand how to adapt my markup to make it work in the carousel. Please can someone give me some pointers on this as I'm totally lost with it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The images slide automatically. carousel controls are not showing here because font files are not attached.

```css
.imslide{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  margin-bottom:80px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.slideim{
  width:100%;
  max-width:100%;
  display:block;
}
.carousel-inner item{
  position:relative;
}
.slide-content{
  position:absolute;
  color:white;
  top:25%;
  left:25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="slider" class="carousel slide imslide forfixhead" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
      <div class="slide-content" id="slide_1_text">
        <h4>navigation made easy !</h4>
      </div>
   <div class="pcimslide">
  <img src="http://www.rokkorfiles.com/photos/360px-rear.jpg" class="slideim"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="slide-content" id="slide_2_text">
        <h4>Distribution in 16 countries</h4>
      </div>
     <div class="pcimslide">
      <img src="http://www.rokkorfiles.com/photos/360PX.jpg" class="slideim"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
```